# How does one express "truthfully", like at the beginning of a sentence in chinese?

Tags: translation, meaning-in-context, expressions

In english I would use "actually", 其实，but the particular thing I am trying to convey is that previously, I gave information that was incorrect, but now I am correcting that information.

“I go to the bar every Sunday afternoon", 我没星期天下午都去餐厅”

"well, actually, I go every afternoon"， 其实啊，每天都我去餐厅喝酒！

Is this an accurate way to express this?

Thanks.

Comment: 其实啊 is fine in this context. But your sentences contain mistakes. "我**每**星期天下午都去餐厅"; "每天我**都去**餐厅喝酒" - note the position of "都".

Answer (score 3):

The disclaimer "**事实上**" implies the previous statement was not totally true or all the facts

- 我在學校打了人也沒有被停課， - I hit someone at school and was not suspended.
- **事实上**，我是被趕出校了 - **In fact**, I was kicked out of school

其实 is less often used as a disclaimer, it is mostly used as a part of a sentence

- 其实我是被趕出校了/ 我其实是被趕了出校